# Dependent objects with RegisterInstance

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container

I am using Unity block for Ioc implementation. I am using registerInstance and thats the way it will be. can't change it. The problem is if we do it what about the dependent objects? How to handle that. lets say

```
public ClientUser(IDataServiceManager dsm)
{
    oDataServiceManager = dsm;
}
```

that works with registerType but as we have to creat the instance first

```
IClientUser clientUser = new ClientUser();
SnapFlowUnityContainer.Instance.RegisterInstance<IClientUser>(clientUser);
```

How can this work? our consultant said, use private getters to set the dependencies, let the class handle its dependent object? couldn't understand how to do that?

---

**Update:** 
I need to know where i am wrong, How it will create the object of Dataservicemanger when i create clientUser
BootStrapper

```
IDataServiceManager dsm = new DataServiceManager();
IClientUser clientUser = new ClientUser();
SnapFlowUnityContainer.Instance.RegisterInstance<IDataServiceManager>(dsm);
SnapFlowUnityContainer.Instance.RegisterInstance<IClientUser>(clientUser);
```

Unit Test:

```
BootStrapper.Register();
IClientUser oIclientUser = SnapFlowUnityContainer.Instance.Resolve<IClientUser>();
```

ClientUser Class:

```
public class ClientUser : UserServiceBase, IClientUser
{
    [Dependency]
    private IDataServiceManager DataServiceMgr { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Is there an overload of the ClientUser constructor you're not showing us? The second code sample seems to suggest that - otherwise it wouldn't compile...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class ClientUser : UserServiceBase, IClientUser   
{
     IDataServiceManager _dataServiceManager;      
     public ClientUser()    
     {             
     }         

     private IDataServiceManager DataServiceMgr     
     {         
          get { 
                _dataServiceManager = SnapFlowUnityContainer.Instance.Resolve<IClientUser>();   
                return _dataServiceManager; 
              }         
       }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If I understand you correctly this should work

```
SnapFlowUnityContainer.Instance.RegisterType<IDataServiceManager, DataServiceManager>();

var clientUser = SnapFlowUnityContainer.Instance.Resolve<ClientUser>();

SnapFlowUnityContainer.Instance.RegisterInstance<IClientUser>(clientUser);
```

`ClientUser` will get the `DataServiceManager` upon `Resolve`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to enable Property injection in Unity, you can put a [Dependency] attribute on the property where you want to enable it. Something like this :

```
[Dependency]
public IClientUser  ClientUser
{
    get { return _clientUser; }
    set
    {
        if (value == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("value",
            String.Format(Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture,
            Properties.Resource.ERR_ARGUMENT_NULL_USERSERVICE));

        _clientUser = value;
    }
}
```

Then, if you use RegisterInstance(clientUser) like in your example, this should work.
Another thing is when you need to to wire up objects not created by the container. Then you should use the method [BuildUp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660934%28v=PandP.20%29.aspx)

Hope this helps,

Thomas

Comment: Is the [Dependency] attribute really necessary? In general Unity supports Property Injection without the [Dependency] attribute, but I don't think I tried it with the combination of the BuildUp method, so it may be required in that specific scenario...

Comment: @Thomas I have updated my code, my internet is acting up a bit, can't google much. can you help me with the buildup thing, i am not sure where to use it. I have a bootstrapper where i am registering my instances and i have unit test where i want to create a clientUser object. Client user has a dependent object called dataservice

Comment: @Mark according to MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650198.aspx Notes on Using Property (Setter) Injection it's mandatory

Comment: @Waqas I looked at your modified example. Why don't you change your bootstrapper code like this :

Comment: IDataServiceManager dsm = new DataServiceManager();
IClientUser clientUser = new ClientUser(dsm);
// unless you need it in other services that _clientUser SnapFlowUnityContainer.Instance.RegisterInstance<IDataServiceManager>(dsm);
       SnapFlowUnityContainer.Instance.RegisterInstance<IClientUser>(clientUser);

Comment: Actaully ClientUser will be used by other Services. And it will also be used as DTO in certain cases. It might create an issue at that time because in case of DTO i wont be creating the object through Container but through concerete class.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need the [Dependency] attribute on properties, it can be done either via a configuration file or the fluent registration API. There's 2 ways of achieving this with the fluent API, for your scenario you will probably use the first method:

Method 1:

```
SnapFlowUnityContainer.Instance
  .Configure<InjectedMembers>()
                    .ConfigureInjectionFor<IClientUser>(
                        new InjectionProperty("DataServiceMgr"));
```

Method 2:

```
SnapFlowUnityContainer.Instance
  .RegisterType<IClientUser, ClientUser>(
                    new ExternallyControlledLifetimeManager(),
                    new InjectionProperty("DataServiceMgr"))
  .BuildUp<IClientUser>(clientUser);
```

Be careful of using "SnapFlowUnityContainer.**Instance**" to register and resolve (service location pattern) types, preferably you need to make sure that registration only occurs once during the application lifetime.